# Validate ID using JSON

Tags: json, forms, validation

I have a JSON file like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"4028c2fe3ec554da013ec557dcb50000",
      "logInformation":{
         "createDate":1369110469000
      },
      "idbarang":"01",
      "nama":"COBA",
      "status":"Tidak Bergaransi",
      "memo":"ddsdsds"
   }
]
```

The JSON data above was created automatically from a database. And I have a form with code like this:

```
<form name="simpanbarang"  id="tambahbarang"> 
  <input type="text" id="id">
  <input type="submit" value="save"> 
</form>
```

I want to validate at submit time and if the value of id is the same as in the JSON file above, then show an alert "data is unavailable".

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this site](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). Here is a sample code for your validation, make needful modifications

```
$(function () {
    /* Varable Declarataion..... */
    var $id                             = $("#id").attr("name");    
    /* Varable Declarataion ends..... */

    var $params             = {debug:false, rules:{}, messages:{}};


    $params['rules'][$id]                                   = {required:true, "jsonValidator":true};
    $params['messages'][$id]                                = {required:"Please enter a value", jsonValidator:"Invalid data"};


    jQuery.validator.addMethod("jsonValidator", function(value, element) {

        var status=false;
        var request = $.ajax( {
            url : "url/fromwhich/youget/jsondata",
            type : "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(data) {

                for (var key in data) {

                    if(key == "id") {
                        if(data[key] == value) {

                            status=true;
                        } else {
                            status=false;
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            },
            async: false
        });

        return status;

    },"Invalid data");

    $("#tambahbarang").validate($params);

});
```